# Need to find/replace values in one column based on the value of the adjacent column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Without having to write VBA code, is there a way to maybe write a formula to do the following:

- iterate (say $i) through each row.
- If value (B,$i) = 2000 & (A,$i) = 1, change (B,i) = 3327

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
=IF(B2=1,C2,IF(C2=2000,3325,IF(OR(C2=2001,C2=102),3327,IF(C2=2003,3329,C2))))
```

Comment: +1 for finding and posting your own answer. Also, to help others who come to this question in the future have clarity, I assume you had that in column D and run it down the rows.

Answer (score 0):

If statement wrapped in a For loop:

```
Dim x    'Beginning Row
Dim y    'Ending Row

For myLoop = x to y
  If Cells(x,1)= 2000 and Cells(x,2) = 1 then
    Cells(x,3 [or a formula to calculate] )=3327
  End If
Next myLoop
```

Comment: My newbie (to here anyways) bad ;)  Time to clean the contacts.